# Wake On LAN questions and problems

Tags: networking, lan, wake-on-lan

I'm attempting to use a PC at home while I'm away, but I'm having some troubles.

- Problem: The PC connects to Internet only with WiFi
- (My possible) Solution: connect a RaspberryPi to the Internet with WiFi and leave it power on; connect it to the PC with a LAN cable and use TeamViewer or Terminal to switch the computer on.

With my knowledge, I couldn't make this setup work.

Of course I've enabled the WOL function in the BIOS settings (Called "PME wake up from S5", hope is that one), but I don't know if I have to set the LAN in a particular way, if I have to power off the pc or only hybernate it, or if this just can't be done.

Comment: Does TeamViewer even run on ARM? Well even if: It'd make more sense to use SSH here to connect to the raspberry pi. Another solution would be to connect the power switch jumpers of your PC's mainboard to a relay that is controled by the raspberry pi's GPIOs.

Comment: Yes, TeamViewer is working great on ARM (I've tried only the client version, so I can connect to it but not from it). 
I'm also SSH into RPI and from there I didn't know what to do.
But the idea of the power jumpers is brilliant! I need to make some research on that. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried sending a magic packet from the RPi yet?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happened. I powered off the pc, not hybernation. Could be this?

Comment: @Gabri You're welcome. Using a relay (or relais depending on where you live, the name differs) has the advantage that both the RPi and the regular power switch can turn the PC on without you having to worry of power flowing back to the Pi. Using GPIOs via command line on the RPi is simple, there are even plenty of templates/how-to's on how to make a webserver on the RPi to control lights or power sockets from anywhere with a web-interface, the exact same thing would work for your case too.

Comment: @confetti Thank you for the detailled answer! I've searched a bit and I've found many different ways to do what you say, but I've no background in electronics. Would you mind to point me to the solution you consider the best? (this is mainly because I've read not to connect directly the RPi and the pc, due to different voltages.. they suggest to buy some plugs but I don't know what are them and I don't want to make a mess) Thanks again!

Comment: This is exactly what a relay takes care of for you. I'm going to leave a full answer with more information and some basic instructions in a couple minutes, it's actually simpler than it sounds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the Raspberry Pi and take advantage of its GPIO pins to control your computer's power switch directly. This has the advantage that you can use Windows 10's fast startup feature, which disables WOL. This also allows you to save energy on the PC side since in order for WOL to work there's never a complete disconnection of power to some components on your PC.

What you need:

- The PC
- The Raspberry Pi (any model will do fine)
- A 5V Relay switch - [Something like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077ZMGT1R)
- Some [female to female](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078H425FG) jumper wires, make sure those are long enough!

The advantage of a relay switch over a direct connection to the Pi is on one hand that your Pi is protected from too much voltage and also this method allows you to keep your PC's regular switch's function.

The wiring diagram for this is simple. First you disconnect your PC's power switch from your mainboard. Then you remove the jumpers on the cable of the switch (the little black connectors) and rip off some of the isolation, so you're left off with the two blank (usually copper) wires.

Here is a quick diagram I made (*I know my artistic skills are outstanding*):
[image: pure art]

Next step is to take two of the female to female jumper wires and do the same that you just did with your switch's cable, on one end of each of the cables. Then put one of the two cables from the switch and one of the two cables from the jumper wires into the `COM` plug on the terminal connector of the relay and screw it tight. Do the same with the other cable from the switch and the other jumper wire, but this time use the `NO` connector of the relay.

After that, plug in the two other ends (with the black jumper connector) from the jumper wires back into the mainboard where your power switch's cables would go. At this point your PC should turn on when you press the power switch of your case.

Now you take three new jumper wires and connect them to the pins on the top of the relay. For easier handling let's say you take a red, a black and a yellow wire. Connect the red one to `VCC` (or `5V+`), the black one to `GND` (or `0V`) and the yellow one to the pin that's left. Usually it's labeled `S` or `IN`.

I'm using this GPIO diagramm for the Raspberry Pi 2 as reference:
[image: GPIO Reference]

Connect the other end of the red wire to `PIN 2` (`5V PWR`), the black wire to `PIN 6` (`GND`) and the yellow wire to `PIN 7` (`GPIO 4`).

Once that is done you can simple SSH into your raspberry pi's console and execute the following commands:

```
# get wiringPi and install it
git clone git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi
cd ./wiringPi
./build
```

This installs the wiringPi library that comes with a `gpio` tool to easily control our GPIOs.

```
# turn PC on
gpio -g mode 4 out && gpio -g write 4 1 && sleep 1 && gpio -g write 4 0
```

That's all. The first part of the command sets the mode of the pin to be an output. The second part sets the output to high, turning the relay on. The third part waits one second and the fourth part turns our relay off again by setting the pin state back to low. This is essentially the same as you holding your PC's power switch for one second.

---

I've tried to be as detailed as possible, but I feel like this can be still very confusing. If you have any question at all feel free to leave a comment so I can elaborate on the confusing parts!

Comment: This is an amazing guide, thank you! The only part which confuse me is the pc power switch connection. Do you mean to "connect" the cable from the switch to the one which goes to the pc, screwing them in the same relè port? in any case, I don't need the power switch on the pc, so I thought to connect the jumpers from the motherboard to the relé. would be ok?

Comment: I've added a wiring diagram, does that make it more clear? It would work without the switch, of course.

Comment: Amazing, at least in theory you solved my problem! I mark the question solved and if I'll have problems once I have all the components, I'll write here. Thanks again

Comment: Ok, I have a problem: once I run your command, the pc powers on. But then, when i switch it off from Windows Start panel, I can't power it on again. I have to reboot the RPi to make it works (this means I have to take off power from the relay. Maybe jumpers are connected wrong in your diagram?)
Interestingly, on the relay, there is one LED on when I can power the PC, but when I switch it off, 2 LEDs are on.

Comment: I've tried using the 3.3V pin instrad of the 5V one and with this command <code>gpio -g mode 4 out && gpio -g write 4 1 && sleep 1 && gpio -g write 4 1 </code> it works, but then, when I want to switch off, I need to run the same command with "0" instrad of "1" as last parameter, or it continue to boot up (because I imagine the circuit is still open).
How can I solve this?

Comment: Is there a reason for the 3.3V instead of 5V? Usually those arrays need 5V, unless you have a 3.3V one. The command in your comment has a `1` at the end when it should be a `0` like I said in my answer. You could write the command from my answer (the `#turn PC on` one) to a file under `/usr/bin` - For example `/usr/bin/turnpcon` and then `chmod +x /usr/bin/turnpcon` it. From then on you will be able to turn your pc run simply by running the `turnpcon` command.

Comment: I don't know, but it works with 3.3V. and the `1` at the end is on purpose, otherwise it won't work.
Infact your command works only the first time I run it. Then, if I switch off the PC and run it again the command from the RPI, it won't work.

Comment: There must be something else wrong then. Putting a `1` at the end will turn the relay on and never off again. Imagine it like this: As long as the relay is on, you're pressing the button. Usually you just press the button for half a second when you turn your PC on. My command first turns it on (`1`), then off (`0`) again after waiting for 1 second. You could try to make the `sleep 1` into a `sleep 2`. Please verify that when running that script the relay turns on (LED on relay should turn on + noticable sound) and turns back off after two seconds.

Comment: There are 2 LEDs: one is always on, the other turns on when I run the command, but never turns back off. When I run the command, I do also hear the click noise

Comment: That's weird. It **is** supposed to turn off after the one second wait, that is what the `0` at the end of my command is for. Do you have a 10k Ohm (12k works too, or something around that) near you by any chance? If so, connect it between the `IN`/`S` line on the relay and `GND` (on the relay or the pi, doesn't matter). This will make sure that your relay will turn off when the pi sets it as `low`. This is called a "pull-down resistor" - You can find more information about this [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=240798.0).

Comment: I don't have it unfortunately, but I'll try to do it.
I've also read online that maybe is because the 'low' and 'high' is set on the 3.3V of the RPi, and giving 5V will always set it as 'high'. Could it be? And without the resistor, what can I do?
Also, the "click" noise is like a sparke: is it normal?

Comment: The 5V is indeed always high, but that's intended as the 5V should go only to the VCC power input of the relay, not the switch input. The problem is that without the resistor the relay's input can get random signals (even from radio waves) so that might cause this issue. Usually relay modules have a resistor built-in, so this shouldn't be an issue, but I can't think of another problem here. Did you try to run `sleep 2` instead of `sleep 1`? I doubt it, but maybe one second wait isn't enough for it to catch up.

Comment: Yes, I've just tried and nothing happens. After the click noise, the LED stays on and nothing happens.
With my other command and 3.3V (the wrong settings) I noticed that if the LED switch off, the pc did the same. Maybe it should stay on?

Comment: If I switch off the pc, the led is still on. But if I reboot the RPi, there is a new "click" and the LED switch off. at the same time the pc powers on but after a few seconds switch off (maybe because the circuit is closed now?)

Comment: **I'm sorry!** - I completely confused NO and NC. Please connect the switch wire that is in `NC` to `NO`. Nothing should be in `NC`. I'm going to update my answer and diagram. Please re-connect the wires and try my script again.

Comment: Actually I've tried before, but the result is the same.

Comment: Really? That's super weird. Having the wires on `NC` means it's constantly like you would press your PCs switch, unless the relay is on. So that would explain the behaviour. Can you double check using `NO` and my script in the answer with a sleep of `2`? If the relay stays on (e.g. you cant hear it turn off again) this is almost certainly because of noise signals in the voltage, and you need a pull-down resistor as I've mentioned above.

Comment: I confirm that even with a sleep of '2' the relay stays on

Comment: Get your hands on a 10k Ohm resistor and try playing it between `IN` and `GND`. It's weird that your relay doesn't have one built-in but I don't see what else could cause this behaviour.

Comment: Ok a little update:
-the first relè was actually missing a resistor: I sent it back;
-I've bought a new relè and now everything works. On this there are no `NO`,`NC`,`COM` references. After some tries, it works perfectly: when I run the command you provided (with `sleep 1` is ok), the relè makes 2 clicks (as it should) and pc stays on.
Thank you @confetti for the support!

Comment: @Backup No problem, I'm glad it all worked out in the end. :)